# Can I use the music from an AI in my video game?

Tags: copyright, music

That's the song that Ai made specific for me, I'm only use the free version, so it is legal to use that song in my video game?

Comment: Why don't you read the T&Cs of the AI in question (if any)?

Answer (score 5):

Context matters. With any legal question, jurisdiction is important - different places have different rules.

Furthermore, "AI" is vague. What are the terms of use on the AI? No one answer here is likely to cover all the possible generative AI tools. Carefully read the label on any of the tools (AI or otherwise) that you are using.

Finally, there's also the platform to consider. For example, [Steam is rejecting games with AI-generated artwork](https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2023/06/steam-mods-reportedly-blocking-games-that-use-ai-generated-artwork/).  Steam's publishing guidelines require you to use content you own or have adequate rights to use. The legal landscape for establishing adequate rights to content generated by the currently available AI tools is at best poorly defined. To that point, In January artists have filed a class-action lawsuit against various generative AI art companies over their use of their copyrighted art as training data. In February Getty Images filed a similar lawsuit. The outcome and its impact on establishing adequate rights remains to be seen. While the focus of that mostly seems to be on visual art, music is subject to the same complications.

Ultimately, legal advice comes from legal experts.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr: Maybe? Nobody knows.**

Generative AI (GAI) is a new field, not just technologically but also legally. In the next years we are going to see a lot on how judges will apply existing laws and how legislators react to these decisions by making new laws.

Is the output of a GAI tool covered by copyright at all? The [US copyright office](https://copyright.gov/ai/ai_policy_guidance.pdf) says no, because they only protect the human input into a work. On the one hand, this would be good for game developers, because it means GAI works are free to use and GAI tool providers will have a hard time to use service terms to stop you. But on the other hand, that also means that GAI works are free for others to steal. So if you don't want someone else to use your AI-generated music, you will have to modify it in a way that fulfills the required creative threshold to be eligible for copyright.

But don't forget that the US copyright office is an executive organ. They just execute existing law. They don't have the authority to make laws, and their legal opinions on existing laws become irrelevant when judges decide otherwise.

And then there is the big elephant in the room: What about the copyright on the training data? Is it copyright infringement when a generative AI tool was trained on copyrighted material? GAI enthusiasts say no, because in their opinion a GAI learns just like a human does: By taking inspiration from work and using that inspiration to create something original. GAI skeptics say yes, because in their opinion GAI copies elements from the artworks it was trained with and then combines them into an amalgamated work that is a derivative of all these artworks.

Who is right? [This is currently a subject of a class-action lawsuit against stable diffusion](https://stablediffusionlitigation.com/). We are probably going to see a lot of legal precedence on this subject in the coming years.

Until then, the answer is unfortunately: **¯\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: And by the way: If you don't want to take the risk, there is plenty of music on websites like soundcloud.com or filmmusic.io that is licensed under permissive licenses like CC-BY which allow you to use it in your game as long as you give credit to the creator.